# Finding the power-series of $\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am going through some old Calculus-tasks in preparation for an upcoming exam, and a seemingly simple task is being stubborn with me. We are simply to find the power-series of the function $$\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$$

Now, we have our basic power-series:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$$

So we have

$$\frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{2(1-\frac{1}{2}x)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}x} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}x + \frac{1}{8}x^2 + \frac{1}{16}x^3 + \cdots$$

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2-x}$. Using the chain-rule, we set $u = 2-x$ and $g(u) = \frac{1}{u}$. Then we have $f'(x) = g'(u) * u' = -\frac{1}{u^2}*(-1) = \frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$

So we have $$\frac{1}{(2-x)^2} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}x + \frac{3}{16}x^2 \cdots$$

The text does not agree on this answer. In particular, it claims that the first term should be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Your answer is perfectly good !

Comment: One of these days I'm going to sue the textbook. :)

Comment: Reality check - put $x=0$ - you are right.

Comment: @AndrewThompson. If you start sueing textbooks for typo's and mistake, perepare yourself for a loooong fight ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using Newton's [generalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) binomial theorem or the Binomial [Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) and assuming the convergence ,

$$\frac1{(2-x)^2} =\frac14\left(1-\frac x2\right)^{-2}$$ 
$$=\frac14\left(1+\frac x2\cdot2+\frac{-2(-2-1)}{2!}\left(\frac x2\right)^2+\cdots\right)=\cdots$$